# How to continue chart when empty points exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, linechart, mschart

`using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`

My data is like so:
[image: sample data]

...but my chart does not draw lines between points of missing data:
[image: incomplete chart]

As you can see, the 2nd column has a point at 51 on 7/09/2015 and then points are empty until 7/16/2015. I want the chart to draw a line from the point at 7/09/2015 to 7/16/2015.

How can I get this to work?

This is my existing `Series` construction:

```
var series = chart.Series[header] = new Series(header) {
    BorderWidth = 2,
    ChartArea = DataTable.TableName,
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine,
    Color = legendColors[header],
    Enabled = true,
    Font = new Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 6f),
    XValueMember = "Week",
    YValueMembers = header
};
```

**Update 1:**
With @jstreet's answer, I am now getting a line drawn. But the value is being represented as if it were 0:
[image: incorrect empty point rendering]

What is expected is the following where thick dashed lines should replace the lines representing a value of 0:
[image: expected empty point rendering]

**Update 2:**
Modified the `for-loop` to manually add `DataPoint`s to the `series` following @jstreet's example for add points in *code-behind*:

```
for (int column = 0; column < seriesHeaders.Length; column++) {
    var header = seriesHeaders[column];

    var series = chart.Series[header] = new Series(header) {
        BorderWidth = 2,
        ChartArea = DataTable.TableName,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine,
        Color = legendColors[header],
        Enabled = true,
        Font = new Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 6f),
        XValueMember = "Week",
        YValueMembers = header
    };
    series.EmptyPointStyle.Color = legendColors[header];
    series.EmptyPointStyle.AxisLabel = "Empty";

    DataTable.Rows
        .OfType<DataRow>()
        .Select(r => (double)r[header])
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(v => {
            series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(series) {
                IsEmpty = v == Double.NaN,
                YValues = new double[] { v == Double.NaN ? 0 : v }
            });
        });

}
```

...chart still renders what is supposed to be an empty point as a `0` value.

**Update 3:**
Modified construction of `DataPoint`s. Evidently `v == Double.NaN` does not evaluate properly:

```
DataTable.Rows
    .OfType<DataRow>()
    .Select(r => (double)r[header])
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(v => {
        var isEmpty = Double.IsNaN(v);
        var value = new double[] { v == Double.NaN ? 0 : v };

        series.Points.Add(new DataPoint() {
            IsEmpty = isEmpty,
            YValues = value
        });
    });
```

... and I verified the `Series.Points` collection:
[image: verified series NaN point IsEmpty]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define an `EmptyPointStyle`, as shown below:

```
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line" XValueType="DateTime">
                <Points>
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="42005" YValues="50" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="42036" YValues="70" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="42064" YValues="30" />
                    <asp:DataPoint IsEmpty="True" XValue="42095" YValues="0" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="42156" YValues="60" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="42186" YValues="40" />
                </Points>
                <EmptyPointStyle Color="Red" />
            </asp:Series>
```

Result:

[image]

EDIT: I can also add points using code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint { IsEmpty = false, XValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToOADate(), YValues = new double[] { 50 } });
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint { IsEmpty = false, XValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToOADate(), YValues = new double[] { 70 } });
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint { IsEmpty = true, XValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToOADate(), YValues = new double[] { 0 } });
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint { IsEmpty = false, XValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).ToOADate(), YValues = new double[] { 30 } });
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(new DataPoint { IsEmpty = false, XValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToOADate(), YValues = new double[] { 60 } });
    }
```

And i don't have the problem you're describing about not being able to set `IsEmpty` or getting 0's in your chart:

[image]

Comment: In my `DataTable`, where values are not provided, I store a Double.NaN. Will this translate to a `Point` where `IsEmpty == true`? I guess I can test that out. But I am trying the `EmptyPointStyle.Color` property. Thanks.

**Result:** `Double.NaN` will result in a `Point.IsEmpty == true`

Comment: ...however, empty points are being drawn with a value of zero (0). See the updated question with a new image.

Comment: Are you sure `IsEmpty` is really set to true? Before adding/binding the data points to the chart?

Comment: Good question ... I'll check

Comment: It can't be set to `IsEmpty == true` prior to the `DataBind()` because points are not assigned until `DataBind()` is called.

Comment: It is up to you to call `DataBind()` at the correct point in time, when your data is ready to go.

Comment: Most likely, I need to add the data points manually to the series. My code simply constructs a series without assigning a `DataPoint[]`. I am letting `DataBind()` do that work. I'll update with results later.

Comment: Updated code to add points manually to `Series` and still getting the `0` value where it should be empty. See updated question. :(

Comment: Are you able to place a break point in the debugger and verify that your series was actually filled correctly?

Comment: It turns out that even though I set `v = Double.NaN`, `v == Double.NaN` returns `false`. That is disturbing. `NaN` is supposed to be a constant: `public const double NaN = 0.0 / 0.0;`

Comment: Oh, there is another method I might be able to use: public static bool IsNaN(double d)

Comment: Another modification but still no change in the chart! :(

Comment: Adding another change: all of your data points have an `XValue != 0`. All of mine are `0`. I'll update in a few with the code change.

Comment: From your original tabular data, all your points have an XValue != 0 too.

Answer (score 0):

Changed one line following all the updates provided:

```
ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line, // was FastLine
```

So the `Series` construction looks like this now:

```
for (int column = 0; column < seriesHeaders.Length; column++) {
    var header = seriesHeaders[column];

    var series = chart.Series[header] = new Series(header) {
        BorderWidth = 2,
        ChartArea = DataTable.TableName,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
        Color = legendColors[header],
        Enabled = true,
        Font = new Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 6f),
        XValueMember = "Week",
        YValueMembers = header
    };
    series.EmptyPointStyle.Color = legendColors[header];
    series.EmptyPointStyle.BorderWidth = 2;

    DataTable.Rows
        .OfType<DataRow>()
        .Select(r => {
            var value = (double)r[header];

            return new {
                isEmpty = Double.IsNaN(value),
                yValue = new double[] { value },
                xValue = DateTime.Parse(r["Week"].ToString()).ToOADate()
            };
        })
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(dp => {
            var dataPoint = new DataPoint() {
                IsEmpty = dp.isEmpty,
                YValues = dp.yValue,
                XValue = dp.xValue
            };

            series.Points.Add(dataPoint);
        });

}
```

The chart is properly rendered:
[image: properly rendered chart]

Comment: Does changing from `Fast Line` to `Line` make any difference?

Comment: Are you saying the problem had nothing to do with using `EmptyPointStyle` ?

Comment: Nope ...that probably needed to be set anyway. Once I set that I was getting the line but it was going to 0 rather than as depicted above.

Comment: Do I get a green check or not...:O)

Comment: I mean.... now that everything works, go back to your code and take out only the `EmptyPointStyle` and see what happens. I just did it in my code and your original problem comes right back at you. So, when you say that `EmptyPointStyle` "probably needed to be set anyway".... I say it was precisely the root of the problem.

Comment: It was a combination of the two issues. I am not opposed to you adding the `Series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line` in which case I will mark yours as the answer. Mine will stay for completeness. I already gave your answer an up-vote because it answered half the solution at the time. :)

Comment: The question was about how to handle missing data. `EmptyPointStyle` solves 100% of that. But thanks for the up vote anyway.

Comment: Btw, once you're so "stingy",,,:O) i would happily trade an up vote for a green check...:O) Thanks again !

Comment: I got it ! Thank you Sir !